# mail jakarta send whit proxy

Tags: proxy, credentials

I can't get through the proxy.  I don't know how to put the domain credentials directly in the program to have access to the email smtp.gmail.com  port. To use internet explorer i need a proxy to be able to use the internet and domain credentials. I tried from ms-dos to run ms-dos with   domain credentials as administrator with the command netsh winhttp import proxy source=ie    but it still doesn't work DEBUG: setDebug: Jakarta Mail version 2.0.1
DEBUG: getProvider() returning jakarta.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Oracle]
DEBUG SMTP: need username and password for authentication
DEBUG SMTP: protocolConnect returning false, host=smtp.gmail.com, user=adrian.gigi, password=
DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true
DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "smtp.gmail.com", port 587, isSSL false
com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectExce`ption: Couldn't connect to host, port: smtp.gmail.com, 587; timeout -1; Using web proxy host, port: proxy.testu.ro, 8080; nested exception is: java.net.ConnectException: connection through proxy proxy.testu.ro:8080 to smtp.gmail.com:587 failed: HTTP/1.1 407 Proxy authentication required at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTP`Transport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:2210)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:722)
at jakarta.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:364)
at jakarta.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:222)
at jakarta.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:171)
at jakarta.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:230)
at jakarta.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:100)
to  send email whit akarta.mail.Authenticator

Comment: PROPERTIES.put("mail.smtp.proxy.host", "proxy.testu.ro");                
PROPERTIES.put("mail.smtp.proxy.port", "8080");  


how to insert domain credentials ?